# Como hacer que mi programa aparezca en la lista de programas de Windows?

Tags: java, windows, lista

tengo una duda, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi programa hecho en Java, salga en la lista de programas instalados en Windows?

¿Alguna clase que me permita hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto no se puede hacer directamente desde Java. Sucede que cuando ejecutas un programa hecho en Java, no ejecutas tu main directamente, lo que ejecutas es la JVM para que ejecute tu programa. Esto es fácil de comprobar cuando ejecutas alguna aplicación desde consola:

```
java <parámetros de la JVM> -cp <ubicación de tus librerías> paquete.de.la.ClasePrincipal
```

Donde `java`, en Windows, es un ejecutable por sí mismo.

Lo que hacen algunos programas como los IDEs hechos en Java (Netbeans, Eclipse, Idea, etc.) es tener un ejecutable nativo del OS (para Windows, archivos .exe) los cuales sí pueden tener un acceso directo. Dentro de estos ejecutables, lo que hay es una llamada al comando `java <parámetros de la JVM> -cp <resto de parámetros> paquete.de.la.ClasePrincipal`.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible opción es añadir a la lista:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Un acceso directo a tu ejecutable.